# Migration error handling to Struts2

Tags: error-handling, struts2, resourcebundle, struts1

To display errors we need message keys which contains the error messages.
I create a new resource bundle named `ApplicationError.properties` which contain this property:

```
app.error=Error: {0}
```

I try to change this class from struts1 to struts2, but I have a problem with error handling.I have not found the equivalent in struts2

```
   public class MyAction extends Action{

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping actionMapping,
                    ActionForm actionForm,
                    HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
                 throws Exception{

    ActionErrors actionErrors = new ActionErrors();
    ActionMessage message = new ActionMessage("app.error","Not Found Exception");


    try{
    //some code

    }catch(NotFoundException e){
        actionErrors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, message);
        saveErrors(request, actionErrors);
        return getErrorActionForward(actionMapping);

    }
    return getActionForward(actionMapping);
}
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [`ActionSupport`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html) class that your action class to extend. Then use its methods to add errors.

This class also implements a `TextProvider`, so you can get localized messages from the resources.

> ```java
> /** Add an Action-level error message to this Action. */
> void  addActionError(String anErrorMessage)
>
> /** Add an Action-level message to this Action. */
> void  addActionMessage(String aMessage)
> ```